# in Blazor I want to use the progress bar to update on saved data within a tabbed container

Tags: blazor, progress-bar, blazor-webassembly, radzen

I am new to using Blazor. I am currently using an app called Radzen. I have a page that uses tabs to complete a checklist. there are 5 tabs in all. In these tabs there is a save button that allows a user to save as they go. I would like the progress bar to track the progress as they save each tab. Is this possible? I am not seeing how to link the progress bar to anything. below is the code. Thanks in advance

```
<RadzenProgressBar Mode="ProgressBarMode.Determinate" ProgressBarStyle="ProgressBarStyle.Success" ShowValue="true" style="width: 274px">
```

Comment: You do know html5 has a native element called `<progress />` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/progress

Comment: I am building a so any elements I can do inside Radzen will save space on the server and save expenses. But it did give me a great idea so thanks for that!!

Comment: That was the point no library required no extra space & increased loading time you get it by default in the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
@bind-Value="@value"
```

found on the official website of radzen [radzen site](https://blazor.radzen.com/progressbar)

Comment: Taking into consideration I can just also just change the value of the progress bar and leave it as a static image versus actually linking it the progress of the page! Thanks